# InsufficientFundsException with JUNIT test

Tags: java, junit

I built an Account class that have 3 properties: balance, owner, acctNo. The Account class have 2 constructors, one that takes 3 properties and one that takes no data. The Account class have set and get methods as well as deposit and withdraw methods.

```
public class Account {
    private int acctNo;
    private String owner;
    private int balance;

    public Account() {
        acctNo = 0;
        owner = "";
        balance = 0;
    }

    public Account(int no, String own, int bal) {
        this.acctNo = no;
        this.owner = own;
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    public int getAcctNo() {
        return acctNo;
    }

    public void setAcctNo(int no) {
        this.acctNo = no;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String own) {
        this.owner = own;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int bal) {
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    public void withdraw(int amt) throws InsufficientFundsException {
        if(amt <= balance) {
            balance -= amt;
        }
        else {
            int newBalance = amt - balance;
            throw new InsufficientFundsException(newBalance);
        }

    }

    public void deposit(int amt) {
        this.balance += amt;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Account ac = new Account(1234, "david", 15000);
        try {
            ac.withdraw(1500);
        }catch(InsufficientFundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Account number: " +ac.getAcctNo());
            System.out.println("owner: " +ac.getOwner());
            System.out.println("Balance is :" +ac.getBalance() );
        }
    }
}
```

I also built an `InsufficientFundsException` class that extend from the `Exception` class. After modify this class to `Account` class, the withdraw method or this `setBalance` method attempts to set the balance below zero, the `InsufficientFundsException` will be thrown.

```
public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception {

    private final int amount;

    public InsufficientFundsException(int amt) {
        this.amount = amt;
    }

    public int getAmt() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

JUnit tester modify the `withdraw()` test method that will attempt to withdraw more than the current balance has available so do the `setBalance()` test method. I need to modify JUnit test for overdrawing the account so that it catches exceptions, and catch the `InsufficientFundsException`.

```
public class AccountTest {

    public AccountTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAcctNo() throws InsufficientFundsException {
        Account instance = new Account();
        int id = 0;
        int number = instance.getAcctNo();
        assertEquals(id, number);       
    }

    @Test
    public void testBalance() throws InsufficientFundsException {
        Account instance = new Account();
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = instance.getBalance();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);

    }

    @Test(expected=InsufficientFundsException.class)
    public void testWithdraw() throws InsufficientFundsException {
        int amount = 0;
        Account instance = new Account ();
        instance.withdraw(amount);
        int balance = instance.getBalance();
        assertEquals(-amount, balance);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeposit() throws InsufficientFundsException {
        int amount = 0;
        Account instance = new Account ();
        instance.deposit(amount);
        int balance = instance.getBalance();
        assertEquals(amount, balance);
    }
}
```

When I run my tests, I get the message:

```
testWithdraw Failed: Expected exception: InsufficientFundsException
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @GhostCat: actually it is in the querstion: testWithdraw Failed.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
if(amt <= balance) {
    balance -= amt;
```

You only throw that exception when AMT is **bigger** than the current balance.

But in your test, you set balance to 0, and amt ... as well. 0 == 0, thus no exception is thrown.

And beyond that: your test case is **overdoing**: as it is

```
@Test(expected=InsufficientFundsException.class)
```

expecting that an exception is thrown, but on the other hand as **last** statement

```
    assertEquals(-amount, balance);
```

you want to compare something. Doesn't make any sense. It is good practice to reduce those test cases where you **expect** an exception to be as **short** as possible. Just do the *minimum* thing to trigger that exception.

A test case should test **one** aspect. Asserting and expecting an exception are already two. And beyond that, the line that could throw happens before the assert. So when the exception would be thrown, the assert will not be invoked in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Your test fixture is not correct.
Because if `account.balance==0` and `amt==0`, this condition is true :

```
 if(amt <= balance) {
```

So `InsufficientFundsException` is never thrown.

Your test could be written :

```
@Test(expected=InsufficientFundsException.class)
public void withdrawWithNotEnoughFund() throws InsufficientFundsException {
    int amount = 1;
    Account instance = new Account();
    instance.withdraw(amount);
    int balance = instance.getBalance();
}
```

Note that `withdrawWithNotEnoughFund()` is more meaningful as `testWithdraw()` as test method name and the assertion after invoking `withdraw()` makes no sense  : `assertEquals(-amount, balance);`) as you don't expect return after the tested method invocation as `InsufficientFundsException` should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

you withdraw `0` from your account in your test. This is OK and does not throw the expected exception so your test fails as you expect the Exception to be thrown.

set the `amount = 1;` in your test so you withdraw more than your account has in balance and the Exception will be thrown and your test will be OK as the expected Exception is thrown.